# dynamic gridview with data columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am using gridview control which having 
i Have to insert the gridview columns dynamic i insert a row values like

i Have to insert the gridview columns dynamic i insert a row values like

```
string[,] mularray = {
                      {"F_1","F_2","F_3","F_4","F_5","F_6"}
                     };

foreach (string names in mularray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {                   
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["10:00-11:00"] = mularray[i, 0];
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["11:00-12:00"] = mularray[i, 1];
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["12:00-01:00"] = mularray[i, 2]; 
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["02:00-03:00"] = mularray[i, 3];
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["03:00-04:00"] = mularray[i, 4];
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["04:00-05:00"] = mularray[i, 5];     
    }   
}
```

when i use this but it is inserting in last row like i shown in picture

next rows values should increment like `F-2,F-3,F_4,F_5,F_6,F_1` then what have to do like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you should be able to do something as simple as the following:

```
string[,] mularray =
{
    {"F_1","F_2","F_3","F_4","F_5","F_6"},
    {"F_2","F_3","F_4","F_5","F_6","F_1"},
    {"F_3","F_4","F_5","F_6","F_1","F_2"},
    {"F_4","F_5","F_6","F_1","F_2","F_3"},
    {"F_5","F_6","F_1","F_2","F_3","F_4"},
    {"F_6","F_1","F_2","F_3","F_4","F_5"}
};

for (int i = 0; i < mularray.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < mularray.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        dt.Rows[i]["10:00-11:00"] = mularray[j, 0];
        dt.Rows[i]["11:00-12:00"] = mularray[j, 1];
        dt.Rows[i]["12:00-01:00"] = mularray[j, 2];
        dt.Rows[i]["02:00-03:00"] = mularray[j, 3];
        dt.Rows[i]["03:00-04:00"] = mularray[j, 4];
        dt.Rows[i]["04:00-05:00"] = mularray[j, 5];
    }
}
```

This iterates through `mularray` in both dimensions. It assigns each row of `mularray` (defined by iterator `i`) to `DataTable dt`. It uses your original loop (redefined with iterator `j`) which assigns values to each of the cells within the current row.

As well, if you are only trying to input a single line and automatically shift elements to the right during each iteration, this can be simplified. You could use the modulo operator (`%`) to cause the elements to loop around, with an offset to select the correct value.

```
string[] mularray = { "F_1", "F_2", "F_3", "F_4", "F_5", "F_6" };

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
        dt.Rows[i]["10:00-11:00"] = mularray[i];
        dt.Rows[i]["11:00-12:00"] = mularray[(i + 1) % 6];
        dt.Rows[i]["12:00-01:00"] = mularray[(i + 2) % 6];
        dt.Rows[i]["02:00-03:00"] = mularray[(i + 3) % 6];
        dt.Rows[i]["03:00-04:00"] = mularray[(i + 4) % 6];
        dt.Rows[i]["04:00-05:00"] = mularray[(i + 5) % 6];
}
```

In this case the `mularray` has been changed to a single dimension `string` array, because both dimensions are not necessary. Now the elements are selected by the calculated index, using `(i + 1) % 6` to represent the pattern of `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0}`. Likewise the next element can be selected by `(i + 2) % 6` which represents `{2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1}`. The first element does not require use of modulo because it uses `i`, which already represents `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`.

Comment: with out using this     {"F_2","F_3","F_4","F_5","F_6","F_1"},
    {"F_3","F_4","F_5","F_6","F_1","F_2"},
    {"F_4","F_5","F_6","F_1","F_2","F_3"},
    {"F_5","F_6","F_1","F_2","F_3","F_4"}     i want to enter dynamically
    {"F_6","F_1","F_2","F_3","F_4","F_5"}

Comment: i got o/p like F_6,F-1,F_2,F_3,F_4,F_5   for every column like this o/p only

Comment: @Meena: What do you mean by `enter dynamically`? Do you want it to automatically move the elements of the array into the correct time slots based on a single input line?